# calculating average amount of order per month in sql

Tags: sql, h2

I have written a query for a h2 db that looks like this

```
SELECT o.order_id,  o.order_date , o.petrol_qty,  (o.price) as price_per_litre , (o.price * petrol_qty) as total_Price, t.truck_code
 FROM ORDERZ o left join truck t ON o.truck_id = t.truck_id
group by o.order_id
```

with a result as such This is for an orderz table

```
ORDER_ID ORDER_DATE PETROL_QTY PRICE_PER_LITRE  TOTAL_PRICE     TRUCK_CODE  
1       2005-01-01     12.0     5.8                69.6           BY2354
2       2006-01-21     13.0     2.8                36.4           BY2994
3       2006-01-21     13.0     2.8                36.4           BY8754
4       2006-01-21     13.0     2.8                36.4           BY8754
5       2006-01-21     13.0     2.8                36.4           BY2354
```

IN TRUCK TABLE I WANT GET average amount of petrol(petrol should be petrol quantity from order table) per month  for each truck 
i am stuck because i dont know exactly how to do a per month average for each truck , any help please.

These are my tables

```
CREATE TABLE truck (
  truck_id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  truck_code VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
  purchased_date VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
  description VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (truck_id)
);

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS order;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS orderz (
  order_id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  petrol_qty DOUBLE NOT NULL,
  price DOUBLE NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  order_date  Date NOT NULL,
  truck_id INT,
  PRIMARY KEY (order_id),
  FOREIGN KEY (truck_id) REFERENCES truck(truck_id)
  ON UPDATE CASCADE
  ON DELETE CASCADE
);
```

NOte- truck_code is unique
i wanted the truck table t to look like 
truck_id truck_code avg_amount_petrol_qty_per_month, i am using only h2 db

Comment: Is truck code unique on truck table?

Comment: yes truck code is unique i will add that to the question thank you

Comment: What are the columns you want on the result data set in addition to truck code, year of the order date, month of the order date and average of the petrol qty?  Does the year matter?  Do you want two rows for January if the year of the two order dates are different?

Comment: it should look like a list of trucks with a avg of petrol quantity ordered per month , so it can be truck_code avg_petrol_qty/month description , then other dates can be added as u sugested

Comment: Using your sample output above, should there be one average for January or two averages (Jan 2005 and Jan 2006) for truck code BY2345?

Comment: that is interesting , I think it should have just an average of a 30 days period , and may be you can show me two options if possible , thank you , for different years is nice , would like to see that as an option

Answer (score 3):

The H2 DB documentation has these functions: `MONTH(date)`, `YEAR(date)` and the aggregate function `AVG()`.  Could use MONTHNAME(date) instead of MONTH(date).
Try this?

A) Group by Truck code, Year and Month:

```
select t.truck_code, year(order_date) as year, month(order_date) as month,
avg(petrol_qty) as avg_petrol_qty from
truck t inner join orderz o
on t.truck_id = o.truck_id 
group by t.truck_code, year(order_date), month(order_date)
order by t.truck_code, year(order_date), month(order_date)
```

B) Group by Truck code and Month:

```
select t.truck_code,  month(order_date) as month,
avg(petrol_qty) as avg_petrol_qty from
truck t inner join orderz o
on t.truck_id = o.truck_id 
group by t.truck_code,   month(order_date)
order by t.truck_code,   month(order_date)
```

Comment: so im getting month(order_date) = numbers , im guessing 1 = january and 2 = february?

Comment: Yes, month() returns 1-12. Could use monthname() instead of month()

Comment: can i do an if statement to say 1 = january or something like this ?

Comment: Try monthname() instead of month().

Comment: @kc2018 Ignore my edit. `MONTHNAME` is a nice way to do it.

Comment: @kc2018  why didnt you use the orderz o alias when doing year(order_date) is it because we are doing an inner join? i expected year(o.order_date)

Comment: You are right. It is better to be specific and use o.order_date in case there is also an order_date in the other tables in scope.  In this particular, it does not matter cos order_date only exists in orderZ.